# Ошибка MySQL при импорте

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Не получается сделать импорт, помогите, будьте добры.

[image: Ошибка MYSQL]

Мой отрывок SQL [image: Code sql]

Comment: Запрос `INSERT INTO` должен оканчиваться на точку с запятой, а у вас там в конце запятая

Comment: А почему вы решили заскриншотить именно этот кусочек вашего SQL? Вам ваш инструмент даже предложил скопировать проблемный запрос, вы могли бы просто скопировать его и попробовать прогнать отдельно от прочего. Он бы упал и вы бы поняли, что проблема именно в нём. Если бы не смогли разобраться, вставили бы этот запрос кодом (а не картинкой) в ваш вопрос.